# Color behind rounded corners iOS

Tags: ios, swift, rounded-corners

[Color of behind rounded corners](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qNMJg.jpg)

How do I change the color that appears behind the rounded corners of the UIImageView ?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Does the source image have transparency around the corners, or are you creating a rounded shape by setting the cornerRadius on the image view's layer? Do you want the corners to show the layer behind the image view? What do you want, exactly?

Answer (score 0):

Set the `UIImageView`'s `backgroundColor`.